# How to get mocha to use http response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

My http call returns a function, so my comparison always fails as [Function] isn't equal to my value.

How can I get my assert to use the true/false flag inside it?

```
# test/helloWorld.js
const other_functions = require('../other_file');
describe('function from other file,visits URL', function() {
  it('should visit example.com', function() {
    result = other_functions.oo
    console.log(result);
    assert.equal(result, true);
  }); 
});
```

```
# other_file.js
const request = require('request')
var http_call = request('http://example.com', function (error, response, body) {
  console.error('error:', error);
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
  console.log('body:', body);
  if(body.match(/Example Domain/)) {
    return true
  }
  else {
    return false
  }
});
exports.oo = () => {
  return http_call
}
```

```
npm test
...
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: [Function] == true       
...
```

Comment: but what do you have inside the returned function? An object, a promise ? Why dont you set the Boolean flag to the contents of the function itself?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2):

Callbacks don't return a value so you need to either pass the callback to get the value or change it to use promise style. Something like this

```
const request = require('request')
function http_call() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request('http://example.com', function (error, response, body) {
      console.error('error:', error);
      console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
      console.log('body:', body);
      if(body.match(/Example Domain/)) {
        resolve(true)
      }
      else {
        resolve(false);
      }
    });
  });
}

module.exports = http_call;
```

and then in your test you can do

```
const http_call = require('../other_file');
describe('function from other file,visits URL', function() {
  it('should visit example.com', async function() {
    const result = await http_call();
    console.log(result);
    assert.equal(result, true);
  }); 
});
```

Hope this helps